# Jacobian for $X = YX'$ where $X',Y,X$ are $n\times n$ matrices?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory

I'm trying to work through this example on the [wiki for Haar measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Examples), showing that

$$
\mu(S) = \int_S \frac{1}{|\det(X)|^n}\,dX
$$

is a left Haar measure for $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. This just comes to doing a simple change of variables $X = YX'$ where $Y\in \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.
Is there a simple way of computing this Jacobian? My first instinct is to relabel $X_{11},X_{12},\ldots X_{nn}$ as $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n^2}$, but this obscures the nice matrix structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear map $L_A \colon M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ given by $L_A(X) = AX$. Denote by $e_{ij}$ the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ and all other entries are zero and consider the ordered basis $\mathcal{B} = (e_{11}, \dots, e_{n1}, e_{12}, \dots, e_{n2}, \dots, e_{1n}, \dots e_{nn})$. With respect to $\mathcal{B}$, the operator $L_A$ is represented by a block diagonal matrix

$$ [L_A]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} A & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \dots & A \end{pmatrix}. $$

Thus, $\det(L_A) = \det(A)^n$ and since $L_A$ is linear, the Jacobian is also $\det(A)^n$.